# Calibration slope for parametric survival model in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, calibration

I have two datasets for parametric survival analysis with weibul distribution: one is for train, the other is for test.
I want to assess the calibration in test datasets.
I tried rms package, but I cannot figure out how to apply test data.

for example,

```
train <- lung[1:100,]
test <- lung[101:nrow(lung),]
s <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = train, dist = "weibul")

#for discrimination
rcorr.cens(predict(s, test), Surv(test$time, test$status)) 

#for calibration
??????????
```

Comment: My memory is that calibration in the rms package did not involve dealing with a dataset that was split. The split-model-test is more along the lines of the caret package paradigm. I think Harrell used a bootstrap approach.

Comment: https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/. Harrell specifically advises against splitting and shows why it is both unstable and inefficient.